# Check if the same text is repeated

Tags: javascript

I setup a website with many posts title.

**HTML structure:**

```
<div class="news-item">
    <h3 class="header">Post title example</h3>
</div>
```

How can I check if the text title is repeated somewhere in the web page ? I mean check if `<h3 class="header">Post title example</h3>` exists more than once on the same page

**Goal:**

I have several areas in the page and for styling needs, I want to check if a Title repeats itself on the page so I will add a class to it `<h3 class="header already-exsit">Post title example</h3>`

Comment: What have you tried ? You could itterate over all html elements (or just all the h3( and filter for the string..

Comment: This sounds like a _xy problem_ where the source of the news should be fixed so that there won't be duplicated news in the first place

Comment: @Andreas Its probably even worse, whos to say there cant be 2 news items with the same title.. ;)

Comment: Are you working with database? if not, then what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have several areas in the page and for styling needs, I want to check if a Title repeats itself on the page so I will add a class to it `<h3 class="header already-exsit"></h3>`

Answer (score 0):

```
let title = 'Post title example'
let headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h3').filter(el => el.textContent === title)
if (headers.length > 1) {
    headers.shift()
    headers.forEach(el => el.classList.add("already-exist"))
}
```

If you have multiple titles you can wrap in a loop.

Comment: `Post title example` is dynamic value and not a one fixed variable.

Comment: You can add loop over headers.